# Proguard does not process onAction calls in FXML

Tags: javafx, proguard, fxml

A lot of my GUI is described in FXML files, and for Buttons and other elements there's an option to set event handler directly from FXML, tied to the method in the controller, set in the same FXML file.
So if there's a class `view.Controller` and there's a method `public void foo()`, then it looks something like this:

```
<StackPane fx:controller="view.Controller" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button onAction="#foo" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

However, after obfuscation with ProGuard it becomes like this:

```
<StackPane fx:controller="b.D" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button onAction="#foo" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

The `foo()` in `view.Controller` gets obfuscated, but the method call in `onAction` does not. I'm using `-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,**.xml,**.css,**.fxml` parameter for this. There's a similar bug where ProGuard does not obfuscate custom controls, which can be solved by removing the imports in FXML and writing fully qualified paths. This workaround can not be used in this situation, I think. What can be done about it except moving all of `onAction` from FXML to `button.setOnAction()` in Java (which is cumbersome and a lot of work)?

I'm using ProGuard 6.0

Comment: So far I've begun writing a tool that would unpack the jar, search for FXML files, there search for #methodCall, change them to obfuscated names from proguard mapping and repack it back to jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I wrote a tiny tool to unpack the jar from ProGuard, rename all onAction calls according to the provided mapping and pack it back to jar again.
[This](https://github.com/graynk/reObfuscateFXML/) is the tool in case anyone needs it (though it's mostly combined from answers on SO and some regex, nothing fancy).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create an annotation named Keep:

```
@Retention(CLASS)
@Target({PACKAGE, TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, METHOD, FIELD})
public @interface Keep {
}
```

Annotate all the methods to keep with @Keep.

```
@Keep
public void onStatsTabSelected(MouseEvent actionEvent) {
            
}
```

and update the *progaurd.conf* to keep anything Annotated with @Keep:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @android.widget.Keep *;
}
```